# How to run index.html using a server(for angularjs and other frameworks)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, httpserver

I have searched stackoverflow and some forums and couldn't find a direct solution and later I came across some ans which works fine so I'm posting it here :)

The ans is for the below folder structure and you can also customize it for your folder structure.

```
--project
---app
----js
----services
----(...)
----index.html
```

Please refer the answer below.
Please post if you have better way to do it and also you can add some comments to make the answer better.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1:

Using node.js to run index.html file copy paste the below code to server.js file in your app folder(above hierarchy)

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  if(/(.*?).css$/.test(request.url.toString())){
     sendFileContent(response, request.url.toString().substring(1), "text/css");
  }else if(/(.*?).js$/.test(request.url.toString())){
    sendFileContent(response, request.url.toString().substring(1), "text/javascript");
  }else if(/(.*?).html$/.test(request.url.toString())){
    sendFileContent(response, request.url.toString().substring(1), "text/html");
  }else if(request.url.toString().substring(1) == ''){
    sendFileContent(response, "index.html", "text/html");
  }
}).listen(3000);

function sendFileContent(response, fileName, contentType){
  fs.readFile(fileName, function(err, data){
    if(err){
      response.writeHead(404);
      response.write("Not Found!");
    }
    else{
      response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': contentType});
      response.write(data);
    }
    response.end();
  });
}
```

and from the app folder run `node server.js`.
Your html file will be serving in localhost:3000

---

### Method 2:

Using http-server. Follow the steps in this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to install http-server globally and from your app folder run cmd 
`http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app`

and your index.html file will be serving in localhost:8000

**Note:** You can change the port number in .listen and -p in above methods.